# Integrating $ e^{3x^2} $

Tags: integration

Let Ω be the region enclosed by the $x–axis$, the line $y = 2x$ and the line $x = 1$.

Calculate

$\iint_{\Omega }^{} e^{3x^2} dxdy $

I simply rewrote this integral as

$ \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{y}{2}} e^{3x^2} dxdy$

However, I can't seem to calculate this Integral. I've tried substitution, no headway there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{^y/_2}e^{3x^2}dxdy = \int_0^1 \int_0^{2x}e^{3x^2}dydx$$

Comment: $u$ substitution anyone?

Comment: Of course. How I miss the obvious solutions I'll never understand.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: swap the order of integration. Then it's easy. :)